# Firefox console access required module in ionic2

Tags: requirejs, ionic2, firefox-developer-tools

I have a very simple `Ionic2` project with some providers that import `pouchdb` library.

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

I want to access `pouchdb` from the console somehow. How can I get that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to access pouchdb from the console somehow.

Assuming that you installed the `pouchdb` dependency by running

```
npm install pouchdb --save
```

And then (optional but recommended) installed typings as well

```
npm install -g typings
typings install --global --save dt~pouchdb dt~pouchdb-adapter-websql dt~pouchdb-browser dt~pouchdb-core dt~pouchdb-http dt~pouchdb-mapreduce dt~pouchdb-node dt~pouchdb-replication
```

Just like you said, you need to import it in your code

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

And then use the `new PouchDB('aName')` method to get an instance of the db. Then you can just use that instance in the console.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyDbClass {

  db: any;

  constructor() {
    this.initializeDb();
  }

  initializeDb(){
    this.db = new PouchDB('aName');
    console.log(this.db);
  }
```